# Play 2.3 JSON convert string to number and validate

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework, type-conversion

I have JSON:

```
{"amount":"123.45"}
```

and I want to convert it to class `case class Record(amount: BigDecimal)`.

Automatic Play reads (`Json.reads[Record]`) works fine until I need to validate whether amount is `> 0.01`. I wrote custom reads:

```
val recordReads: Reads[Record] = (
    (JsPath \ "amount").read[String].map(x => BigDecimal(x))(min(BigDecimal("0.01")))
)(Record.apply _)
```

but this solution makes compilation error `Cannot prove that scala.math.BigDecimal <:< scala.math.BigDecimal => C.`. The same if I change `BigDecimal` with `Double` etc.

**How can I transform string to `BigDecimal` and also validate at the same time?** Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Why not `(__ \ "amount").read[BigDecimal].filter(_ > BigDecimal(0.01))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to define the reads looks like this:

```
val recordReads: Reads[Record] = (
  (JsPath \ "amount").read[BigDecimal](
    min(BigDecimal("0.01"))
  )
).map(Record.apply _)
```